# Query Drop Down Lists that talk to each other

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have data like this:

[image]

Sorry I can't share the data because its PHI, but pretty basic data frame with those column headers.

Following [this guys video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLW8SerwnJo) almost exactly I've created two drop down lists on this page:

[image]

In that drop down list you can for instance select "Facial Trauma" in the category 1 drop down and all the rows with "Facial Trauma" in Category 1 will show up.

Works great.  My problem is that some rows might have "Facial Trauma" in Category 1, and some rows might have "Facial Trauma" in Category 2, and I'd love for the Sorter to show it either way.

Examples include:

- Study is "Facial Trauma" category 1 and "NeuroPlastics" category 2.  When I pick "Facial Trauma" in the sorter it shows up.
- Study is reversed of that, Facial Trauma is Category 2.  Still shows up.

You would think I could maybe just drop one of the sorter category variables, but I'd still love to be able to filter specifically to studies that were tagged with BOTH Facial Trauma AND Neuroplastics if I'd like.

So picking "Facial Trauma" in the first sorter would still get studies where Facial Trauma was in the second column.  Does that make sense?

**Edited to include a link to dummy data:**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WrMF8DVnVt186-OJ-X_maeq3EOZeX_8jXqu4aMTj1MM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you provide a sample spreadsheet with dummy data? It is difficult for us to replicate your issue with the given sample data. Also kindly include the formula in your post above.

Comment: Can't access dummy sheet.

Comment: Hmm... I literally just made a change to the address so that people who click it could view/download it but not edit the one in my drive.  I'm not sure if you tried before/after that.  Does it still not work?  I apologize for the difficulties

Comment: I was able to view your dummy spreadsheet now.

Comment: Apologies but I'm still confused on what the output should look like especially if Category 2 contains Facial Trauma. What will happen if there is value to Category 2 in Sorter Sheet other than `all`? Should the row that has Facial Trauma in Category 2 be included? Would you mind adding test cases or expected output of different Categories combinations in your sheet? Also, adding example of rows that has Facial Trauma in Category 2 would be helpful.